# CSS horizontal scroll mobile only

Tags: css, scroll

I am trying to add a horizontal scroll bar on mobile-only however the media query that I do doesn't display on mobile devices:

```
@media (min-width:480px) {   
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 4px;
        width: 4px;
        overflow: visible;
        border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #eeeeee;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #b0b0b0;
    }
}
```

It seems that it doesn't trigger when I go into mobile view.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: try to use `max-width` instead of `min-width`

Comment: @Aman That seemed to work

Comment: Hi Marc. Please install and use an English spell-checker for your work here. It's OK if your first language is not English, but we'd rather people used tools to make their work as readable as possible. Stack Overflow is intended to be a set of curated Q&A for a wide future audience, and not just a set of posts useful to their immediate authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as pointed out by Aman, `@media (min-width:480px) {}` will trigger on screens **bigger than 480px**. If you want a query triggered below 460px try `@media (max-width: 480px) {}`.

Secondly, your CSS code is **styling** the scroll bar rather than activating/deactivating scroll, which is what I understand you need.

To activate horizontal scrolling on mobile only try:

```css
.selector {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;  /* <-- this enables horizontal scroll */
}

@media (min-width: 480px) { /* <-- For screens bigger than 480px */
    .selector {
        overflow-x: hidden;  /* <-- this disables it */
    }
}
```